# How to define variables within Eloqua to store information that can be used in emails?

Tags: email, html-email, eloqua

New to using Eloqua, and I can see that it doesn't support javascript. I want to store information under variables like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p id="p1"></p>
    <p id="p2"></p>

    <script>
        var Event_Title = 'NA', Speaker = 'XYZ'         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And use them in the email templates with something like this:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = Event_Title;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = Speaker;
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Are you talking about merge tags, perhaps? https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/EmailEditing/Tasks/AddingFieldMergesToEmails.htm

Answer (score 0):

Email clients (i.e. Outlook) don't support Javascript.

What you need is Dynamic Content to show the content based on a field value.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/DynamicContent/DynamicContent.htm

Alternatively, as suggested, a field merge from a CDO would be possible.

Comment: Understood. In my case, I don't need details for the event(date, speaker, etc.) to change for a particular campaign, it remains same for all recipients. However I have numerous events in a month. Currently I just duplicate the template and manually edit for the changes in the template for each event. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: @user18482292 it sounds like you're looking for an equivalent to Marketo's Program Tokens to store the data at the campaign level? If I were you, I would consider using a single campaign (or perhaps multiple) that stamps an event ID to the contact before the email send, and then use a dynamic content module looking at that stamped event ID value. All you would need to do is update the dynamic content, just re-use the same email.